# Open GL Rotate Object

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to rotate an object in Open GL.  I can successfully draw a square, but when I try to rotate it stays in the same place.  I have tried to move around the order of the lines below but still doesn't work, (doesn't draw at all with certain order or certain lines removed)...  here's the code i have so far, mAngle is a random float between 0 and 360.

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Matrix.setRotateM` creates a new matrix for rotation by angle a (in degrees) around the axis (x, y, z).
`Matrix.setLookAtM` defines a new viewing transformation in terms of an eye point, a center of view, and an up vector.
Both operations do not manipulate a input matrix, they create a complete new matrix by their parameters and write it to the output `rm`.

In compare, with `Matrix.rotateM` a given matrix is rotated.

See [android.opengl - `Matrix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html)

You have to create a separated view matrix by `Matrix.setLookAtM`:

```
Matrix viewM = new Matrix();
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewM, 0, 0, 0, 5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
```

and you have to multiply it to the roation matrix (model matrix) by `Matrix.multiplyMM`:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, viewM, 0, modelM, 0);
```

I recommend writing the code like this:

```
Matrix modelM= new Matrix();
Matrix.setRotateM(modelM, 0, mAngle, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);

Matrix viewM = new Matrix();
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewM, 0, 0, 0, 5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);

Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, viewM, 0, modelM, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with your code.  Been trying to figure it out for a few hours.